# get notification from single table and join with multiple tables and result as single array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a table like [image]

and select all notifications from this table and join with below mentioned tables

1. tbl_notice
   [image]
2. tbl_task

[image]

3. tbl_assignment

[image]

and i am trying to fetch datas from tables like

```
$sql = "select * from(
    (
    SELECT a.refer_id as id ,a.refer_tbl,b.task_name as name FROM tbl_notification as a
    LEFT JOIN tbl_task as b ON (a.refer_id= b.task_id )ORDER BY a.created_date desc
    ) UNION
    (
    SELECT c.refer_id as id ,c.refer_tbl, d.notice_title as name FROM tbl_notification as c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_notice as d ON (c.refer_id = d.notice_id)ORDER BY c.created_date desc
    ) UNION
    ( 
    SELECT e.refer_id as id,e.refer_tbl, f.title as name FROM tbl_notification as e
    LEFT JOIN tbl_assignment as f ON (e.refer_id = f.assignment_id) ORDER BY e.created_date desc
    ))";
   $query= $this->db->query($sql)->get();
```

the result shows the data from first table where  join (in case tbl_task) other tbl_notice and tbl_assignment details are null result demo like this
[image]

Please help me to correct this.....

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of the data. Post the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing a LEFT (OUTER) JOIN when it sounds like you're needing a plain old (INNER) JOIN. Try this:

```
SELECT a.refer_id as id ,a.refer_tbl,b.task_name as name FROM tbl_notification as a
JOIN tbl_task as b ON (a.refer_id= b.task_id )ORDER BY a.created_date desc
UNION
SELECT c.refer_id as id ,c.refer_tbl, d.notice_title as name FROM tbl_notification as c
JOIN tbl_notice as d ON (c.refer_id = d.notice_id)ORDER BY c.created_date desc
UNION
SELECT e.refer_id as id,e.refer_tbl, f.title as name FROM tbl_notification as e
JOIN tbl_assignment as f ON (e.refer_id = f.assignment_id) ORDER BY e.created_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer with below attach code

```
select * from ( SELECT a.refer_id as id ,a.refer_tbl,a.created_date,b.task_name as name FROM tbl_notification as a JOIN tbl_task as b ON (a.refer_id= b.task_id AND a.refer_tbl="tbl_task") 
           UNION SELECT c.refer_id as id ,c.refer_tbl,c.created_date, d.notice_title as name FROM tbl_notification as c JOIN tbl_notice as d ON (c.refer_id = d.notice_id AND c.refer_tbl="tbl_notice")
           UNION SELECT e.refer_id as id,e.refer_tbl,e.created_date, f.title as name FROM tbl_notification as e JOIN tbl_assignment as f ON (e.refer_id = f.assignment_id AND e.refer_tbl="tbl_assignment") ) tbl_notification ORDER BY `tbl_notification`.`created_date` desc
```

Thaks for helping me.....